# Transient mode for unit tests with jclouds and Openstack Swift doesn't work

Tags: java, unit-testing, openstack-swift, jclouds

I just migrated to jclouds 2.0.0 (it was suppose to some of the problems with not repeatable operations and it did). Here are the dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.driver</groupId>
        <artifactId>jclouds-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>openstack-keystone</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>openstack-swift</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I want to have unit tests for my code. But when I use `transient` as a provider:

```
SwiftApi swiftApi = ContextBuilder.newBuilder("transient")
                .endpoint(endpoint)
                .credentials(user, password)
                .modules(modules)
                .overrides(overrides)
                .buildApi(SwiftApi.class);
```

I get this exception:

```
com.google.inject.ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:

1) No implementation for org.jclouds.openstack.swift.v1.SwiftApi was bound.
  while locating org.jclouds.openstack.swift.v1.SwiftApi

1 error

    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1004)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1009)
    at org.jclouds.ContextBuilder.buildApi(ContextBuilder.java:651)
    at org.jclouds.ContextBuilder.buildApi(ContextBuilder.java:643)
    at eu.europeana.cloud.service.mcs.persistent.swift.SimpleSwiftConnectionProvider.openConnections(SimpleSwiftConnectionProvider.java:91)
    at eu.europeana.cloud.service.mcs.persistent.swift.SimpleSwiftConnectionProvider.<init>(SimpleSwiftConnectionProvider.java:67)
    at eu.europeana.cloud.service.mcs.persistent.swift.SimpleSwiftConnectionProviderTest.getContainer(SimpleSwiftConnectionProviderTest.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

The same code run with `openstack-swift` as provider (and correct credentials and endpoint) works just fine.
Passing any other string as `newBuilder` function parameter cause:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: key [wrongstring] not in the list of providers or apis: {apis=[openstack-keystone, openstack-swift, transient]}
    at org.jclouds.ContextBuilder.newBuilder(ContextBuilder.java:175)
```

which made me think that `transient` should be supported. But how to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create a `SwiftApi` view of a transient blobstore; instead you must use the portable `BlobStore` view:

```
String provider = ...;  // openstack-swift or transient
BlobStoreContext context = ContextBuilder.newBuilder(provider)
            .endpoint(endpoint)
            .credentials(user, password)
            .buildApi(BlobStoreContext.class);
BlobStore blobStore = context.getBlobStore();
// interact with blobStore, e.g., get, put
...
context.close();
```

Comment: That's what I did in the end and it works... But first it's a little sad, that you cannot unit test SwiftApi code. And second: the exception is listing available providers is just wrong and misleading.

Comment: SwiftApi and transient have different APIs and you cannot just plug one into the other.  The BlobStore code implements this portable layer.  If you want a testing Swift server you can use SwiftProxy: https://github.com/bouncestorage/swiftproxy

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Is there any advantage of using SwiftApi over Blobstore? I was using it before jclouds v2 and it works perfectly fine right now but the documentation suggests using SwiftApi: https://jclouds.apache.org/guides/openstack/#swift
Should I consider it?

Comment: Generally users call the BlobStore API for most operations so that their application is portable.  When users need additional functionality only exposed by SwiftApi they call into that in specific call sites.  One example is getting the container size in bytes, not exposed by all blobstores, and thus only part of SwiftApi.